# Retrieve yerr value from bar object in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

How can I retrieve a yerr value from an ax.bar object?
A bar chart is created with a single line, each parameter of the ax.bar() is a collection, including the yerr value.

```
bar_list = ax.bar(x_value_list, y_value_list, color=color_list,
                  tick_label=columns, yerr=confid_95_list, align='center')
```

Later on, I want to be able to retrieve both the y value as well as the yerr value of each individual bar in the chart.
I iterate through the bar_list collection and I can retrieve the y value, but I don't know how to retrieve the yerr value.

Getting the y value looks like this:

```
for bar in bar_list:
    y_val = bar.get_height()
```

How can I get the yerr? Is there something like a bar.get_yerr() method? (It isn't bar.get_yerr())
I would like to be able to:

```
for bar in bar_list:
    y_err = bar.get_yerr()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that in the above example `confid_95_list` **is** already the list of errors. So there is no need to obtain them from the plot.

To answer the question: In the line `for bar in bar_list`, `bar` is a `Rectangle` and thus has no errorbar associated to it.

However `bar_list` is a bar container with an attribute `errorbar`, which contains the return of the errorbar creation. You may then get the individual segments of the  line collection. Each line goes from `yminus = y - y_error` to `yplus = y + y_error`; the line collection only stores the points `yminus`, `yplus`. As an example:

```
means = (20, 35)
std = (2, 4)
ind = np.arange(len(means))   

p = plt.bar(ind, means, width=0.35, color='#d62728', yerr=std)

lc = [i for i in p.errorbar.get_children() if i is not None][0]
for yerr in lc.get_segments():
    print (yerr[:,1]) # print start and end point
    print (yerr[1,1]- yerr[:,1].mean()) # print error
```

will print

```
[ 18.  22.]
2.0
[ 31.  39.]
4.0
```

So this works well for symmectric errorbars. For asymmectric errorbars, you would additionally need to take the point itself into account.

```
means = (20, 35)
std = [(2,4),(5,3)]
ind = np.arange(len(means))   

p = plt.bar(ind, means, width=0.35, color='#d62728', yerr=std)

lc = [i for i in p.errorbar.get_children() if i is not None][0]
for point, yerr in zip(p, lc.get_segments()):
    print (yerr[:,1]) # print start and end point
    print (yerr[:,1]- point.get_height()) # print error
```

will print

```
[ 18.  25.]
[-2.  5.]
[ 31.  38.]
[-4.  3.]
```

At the end this seems unnecessarily complicated because you only retrieve the values that you initially put in, `means` and `std` and you could simply use those values for whatever you want to do.